# Hyper-V Remote Management Domain > Workgroup

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having trouble connecting my Hyper-V Server manager on a windows 8.1 client to a remote Server 2012R2 Hyper-V Server. The Client is on a domain and the server is in a workgroup outside the network.  When I try to add the server I'm getting the error:

```
"RPC server unavailable.  Unable to establish communication between [SERVER] and [CLIENT]"
```

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Added the remote server as a trusted host to the client machine
2. added credentials for the remote server to the client using `cmdkey /add:[SERVERFQDN] /user:[SERVERHOSTNAME]\[USER] /pass:[PASSWORD]`
3. Ran winrm quickconfig on the server
4. Manually set DCOM permission to allow anonymous logon on the client and the server
5. Added the hostname of the server to the client's hosts file
6. Rebooted the server
7. Added the local administrator on the server to the Hyper-V Administrator's group
8. Both firewalls were off during testing

I've downloaded and run **hvremote /show /target:[SERVERFQDN]** and can see that there is a problem:

```
- Connect to root\virtualization WMI namespace
      FAIL - Connection attempt failed

      - Have you run hvremote /add:user or hvremote /add:domain\user
        on the remote computer to grant access?

      - Are you sure the computer name has been entered correctly?

      - Are you sure the remote computer is running Hyper-V?
```

On the server I've run **hvremote /add:"CLIENTDOMAIN\MY LOGIN"** and get the following error:

```
 ***** GetTrustee Failed: CLIENTDOMAIN\MY LOGIN not found
***** If [DOMAIN] is a domain, you need to be connected to the domain for this to work
```

At this point I'm at a loss.  What steps have I missed? Any tips or help anyone could give would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I've done to add a workgroup server in Server manager to my domain computer running Server manager.

On the computer that is running Server Manager, your Win 8.1 client, add the workgroup server name to the TrustedHosts list.  For example, to add the WGroupSrv computer to an existing list of trusted hosts, use the following command in Poweshell as an admin.

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts WGroupSrv -Concatenate -Force
```

I know you said both firewalls are off, so the following probably isn't helpful, but if your Domain Client computer and your Workgroup server are not in the same subnet, on the workgroup server, change the inbound Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In) setting in the Windows Firewall to allow connections from remote computers by adding the computer name of your Win 8.1 Client on the Remote Computers tab of the WMI (HTTP-In) setting’s Properties dialog box in Windows Firewall.

Comment: The fully qualified domain name of the remote server is already in my trusted hosts list. I confirmed this with `ls WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts | select -ExpandProperty Value` .  For kicks I also added the hostname but no luck.

Comment: Ok.  So the workgroup server is in your trusted hosts list.  What do you see in you domain client Server Manager \Manage \Add Servers \DNS tab after typing in the workgroup server name?  Does the name appear in DNS?  If so, what message do you get after clicking "enter”, moving the server to the right hand pane and clicking ok?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Art.  Actually I already have the server in question in Server Manager on the client computer and it's reporting the server's IP and Managebility status etc just fine.

Comment: Right clicking the server in Server Manager and Selecting Hyper-V Manager gives the same error.

Comment: Ah ok.  Try this.  In serve manager, find your workgroup server, right click the workgroup server and select “manage as”, fill in the local admin credentials as "workgroup server name\administrator" (or whichever local admin account is on the server), check the box to remember the credentials if you wish, and then click ok.  What happens?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that already :) I retried it and again it connects via server manager just fine but right clicking and selecting hyper-v manager gives the RPC error.

Comment: I am sorry to hear it's not working.  We've went through all of the steps I've done myself to accomplish this.  I am just curious, can you do other things on the workgroup server from server manager?  For example, right clicking it and selecting Computer mgmt, etc.?

Comment: All the functions of Server Manager work fine, that's why I'm baffled.

Comment: Yeah.  Bizarre.  Just a shot in the dark.  Do you have the latest version of HVRemote?  I remember there was a version of hvremote that didn't support win8 and srv2012.  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6#content

Comment: I redownloaded it but still no joy :\ bizarre.

Comment: It really is.  At this point, I would setup a test VM in your workgroup subnet and go through the process to see if it works.